# XML / XSD validation how to ignore xml element

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an XML snippet like below:

```
<Type>
    <name>content1</name>
    <priority></priority>
    <schedule>30 0/1 * * * ?</schedule>
    <length>2</length>
    <patterns>
        <pattern>[^\s]*\.DOC</pattern>
    </patterns>
</Type>
```

Some 'type' tags will not contain the

```
<priority></priority>
<schedule>30 0/1 * * * ?</schedule>
```

elements.  But when I validate it against the given 'XSD' file it will throw an error.  How can I ignore or check if the tags are available validate it condition on the XSD file?  Is it possible?

I am using Java Validator to validate this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This example might be helpful: http://java-by-ash.blogspot.com/2012/07/xml-schema-validation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XSD file, make the <priority> & <schedule> optional. Setting the minOccurs to 0 make the element optional. If the elements exists in the xml the xsd will validate it, if not, the xsd won't validate it.

```
Example:

<xs:element name="priority" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="schedule" minOccurs="0"/>
```